# getText result is 0 instead of string (cucumber/javascript)

Tags: javascript, cucumber, webdriver-io

I'm trying to assert the text from an error msg on a login form and I'm using cucumber to do this. The step is:

```
And  I expect that element "li.error" contains the text "Your username and password didn't match. Please try again."
```

This again is using:

```
    Then(
    /^I expect that (button|element) "([^"]*)?"( not)* contains any text$/,
    checkContainsAnyText
```

And this again is using:

```
module.exports = (elementType, element, falseCase, expectedText) => {

let command = 'getValue';

if (
    elementType === 'button' ||
    browser.getAttribute(element, 'value') === null
) {
    command = 'getText';
}

/**
 * False case
 * @type {Boolean}
 */
let boolFalseCase;

/**
 * The expected text
 * @type {String}
 */
let stringExpectedText = expectedText;

/**
 * The text of the element
 * @type {String}
 */
const text = browser[command](element);
console.log(text);

if (typeof expectedText === 'undefined') {
    stringExpectedText = falseCase;
    boolFalseCase = false;
} else {
    boolFalseCase = (falseCase === ' not');
}

if (boolFalseCase) {
    expect(text).to.not.contain(stringExpectedText);
} else {
    expect(text).to.contain(stringExpectedText);
}
```

};

the error msg I get is:

```
expected '0' to include 'Your username and password didn\'t match. Please try again.'
```

The HTML on the page is:

```
<div class="messages">
            <ul>

                    <li class="error">
                        ::before 
                        Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.
                    </li>                  
            </ul>
        </div>
```

I can't figure out why this is not working, I've used the same step in a different part of the same test (and countless other test features) asserting an H1 element and the text it contains and this works like a charm.

As you can see, I've added a console.log(text) to show me what text is found when using this test step. In other steps it shows me the correct text found but for this part it just returns 0

Comment: Hi Hugo, could you try to get the text directly through: driver.findelement(By.xpath("//li[@class='error']").getText; ?

Comment: isn't the code above Java? The cucumber env I use makes use of Javascript so that wouldn't work. Also, that still does not explain why it does work for some elements and not for others. Thanks for th suggestion though.